# How to convert js nested object to php array

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to convert js object in php array it is working but inside that object there are more objects which also need to convert in array

here is how i am converting

```
$data = json_decode($order->data,true);
           dd($data);
```

result

```
array:12 [
  "paymethod_id" => 1
  "business_id" => 76
  "delivery_type" => "1"
  "driver_tip" => 0
  "delivery_zone_id" => 6569
  "delivery_datetime" => null
  "location" => array:2 [
    "lat" => 18.7675049
    "lng" => -103.1445221
  ]
  "deliveryOptionmodal" => array:3 [
    "id" => 2
    "value" => "Esperar en la entrada"
    "$$hashKey" => "object:525"
  ]
  "delivery_cost_new" => 20
  "products" => "[{"id":48732,"code":"NPxRSw","quantity":1,"options":[],"ingredients":[]}]"
  "customer_id" => 129731
  "customer" => "{"id":129731,"name":"bil","middle_name":null,"lastname":"ar","second_lastname":null,"photo":null,"email":"bilal1212@gmail.com","cellphone":"0213123132131","address":"Coalcomán, Michoacán, Mexico","location":"{\"lat\":18.7675049,\"lng\":-103.1445221}","internal_number":null,"address_notes":"sss","zipcode":null,"map_data":{"library":"google","place_id":"ChIJz6WGrUw-MIQR_jYIoFZ-RPM"},"tag":"home"}"
]
```

You can see customer and product object is not converted into array how i can do that?

Comment: If they are strings before they are stringified in js, they will remain strings in php. You can see that it works correctly for location and deliverOptionmodal, so the error is likely in the js.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms, you are sending an `JSON` encoding of an `JSON` object, with properties that are already encoded. You can send the correct data which is the correct solution, but sometimes wrong solutions needs to be made to fix existing problems.

Then just decode the properties and you should be fine.

```
$data = json_decode($order->data, true);

$data['products'] = json_decode($data['products'], true);
$data['customer'] = json_decode($data['customer'], true);
```